# how can i remove js file from my footer in wordpress

Tags: theme-development, jquery, wp-enqueue-script

i want to remove a specific js file from specific template. i have seen sone solutions and try them but got no result. following i am writing the code which i tried.

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','theme_slug_dequeue_footer_jquery');
function theme_slug_dequeue_footer_jquery() {
   
     if ( is_page_template('property_list_half.php') ) {
       wp_dequeue_script('directory-js');
       wp_deregister_script('directory-js');
     }      
   }
```

[image: following the image of file i want to remove]

Comment: Perhaps try to set the priority later - like 100 - ```add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','theme_slug_dequeue_footer_jquery', 100 );```

Comment: Also try just using `directory`. I believe the `-js` part is added by WordPress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out. The -js is added by WordPress, so you don't need it when you are calling it.

```
function theme_slug_dequeue_footer_jquery() {

    if ( is_page_template('property_list_half.php') ) {
        wp_dequeue_style( 'directory' );
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','theme_slug_dequeue_footer_jquery');
```